# Creating BOOL col based on conditional criteria

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda

I have a pandas DF and am looking to test if a column contains a certain string in the cell.

I used list comprehension to create a `list` of values from df["Situation"] that had "Standalone" in the value.

I wanted to test membership against this list, and if the value existed here then return FALSE .

```
`df['Standalone'] = df.apply(lambda x: x == 'FALSE' if ['Situation'] not in 
true_std_list else 'TRUE', axis=1)`
```

Pandas throws an error re; series ambiguous.

any ideas?

Comment: `df['Standalone'] = df['Situation'].isin(true_std_list)`